# Send push notification to Android, with laravel-push-notification

Tags: php, android, laravel, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

A laravel-push-notification addon for laravel 5: https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification

In my routes.php, I have:

> Route::get('/test_gcm', 'TestGCMController@index');

TestGCMController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\Facades\PushNotification;

use App\Http\Requests;

class TestGCMController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    // Change it when device launching sometimes
    $deviceToken = "12345";

    $return = PushNotification::app('appNameAndroid')
      ->to($deviceToken)
      ->send('Hello World, i`m a push message');

    var_dump($return);
  }
}
```

so when I visit site.com/test_gcm

The var_dump returns:
[image]

I am not sure it is successfully or failure. There is no indication in the image.

The android app is from this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/, I am able to get the GCM token, so the app is not working, but I don't receive any notification from the Android phone in emulator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to send push notificaton on users mobile , hope it will helps you :

```
function sendPushNotification($fcm_token, $title, $message, $id="") {  
        $push_notification_key = Config::get('settings.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_KEY');    
        $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";            
        $header = array("authorization: key=" . $push_notification_key . "",
            "content-type: application/json"
        );    

        $postdata = '{
            "to" : "' . $fcm_token . '",
                "notification" : {
                    "title":"' . $title . '",
                    "text" : "' . $message . '"
                },
            "data" : {
                "id" : "'.$id.'",
                "title":"' . $title . '",
                "description" : "' . $message . '",
                "text" : "' . $message . '",
                "is_read": 0
              }
        }';

        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 120;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        // Get URL content
        $result = curl_exec($ch);    
        // close handle to release resources
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: where should `push_notification_key` come from?

Comment: push_notification_key is our project id

Please check here my comments

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54017664/laravel-push-notidfication-and-messaging/54017988#54017988