# Laravel Push Notification and Messaging

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, push-notification, messaging

I'm trying to write front-end with the back-end ionic with laravel.
What I want to do is that when the user orders the application, I want to send notifications to the application and messaging with the user from the application.

For this, I have reviewed the / laravel-push-notification package;

However, it did not work for me because I needed a dynamic messaging. Can you help with this? I do not want to use https://pusher.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also integrated push notification in laravel using below code, hope it helps you :

```
function sendPushNotification($fcm_token, $title, $message, $id="") {  
        $push_notification_key = Config::get('settings.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_KEY');    
        $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";            
        $header = array("authorization: key=" . $push_notification_key . "",
            "content-type: application/json"
        );    

        $postdata = '{
            "to" : "' . $fcm_token . '",
                "notification" : {
                    "title":"' . $title . '",
                    "text" : "' . $message . '"
                },
            "data" : {
                "id" : "'.$id.'",
                "title":"' . $title . '",
                "description" : "' . $message . '",
                "text" : "' . $message . '",
                "is_read": 0
              }
        }';

        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 120;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        // Get URL content
        $result = curl_exec($ch);    
        // close handle to release resources
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: only fcm is enough?

Comment: Also we require push_notification_key, I have already used it in on of my project and its working fine with FCM and Push Notification Key (that is project id)

Comment: what is the project id?

Comment: When register our project in firebase for push notifications, there project id is generated and we will used it here..

We can say FCM and Push Notification Key (that is firebase project id)

Comment: Would it be a nuisance to use this structure with ios or android?

Answer (score 1):

```
function sendPushNotification($fcm_token, $title, $messages, $id="") {  
        $push_notification_key = Config::get('settings.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_KEY');    
        $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";            
        $header = array("authorization: key=" . $push_notification_key . "",
            "content-type: application/json"
        );    `enter code here`

        $postdata = '{
            "to" : "' . $fcm_token . '",
                "notification" : {
                    "title":"' . $title . '",
                    "text" : "' . $messages . '"
                },
            "data" : {
                "id" : "'.$id.'",
                "title":"' . $title . '",
                "description" : "' . $messages . '",
                "text" : "' . $messages . '",
                "is_read": 0
              }
        }';

        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 120;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        // Get URL content
        $result = curl_exec($ch);    
        // close handle to release resources
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;enter code here
    }
```